# How do I concat/flatten byte arrays

Tags: audio, clojure, io, clojure-java-interop

I'm making a function that generates a .wav file. I have the header all set, but I'm running into trouble with the `data` itself. I have a function for creating a sine wave at 880Hz (at least I think that's what it does, but that's not my question)--the question is, how do I convert a collection of byte arrays to just one byte array with their contents? This was my best try:

```
(defn lil-endian-bytes [i]
  (let [i (int i)]
  (byte-array
    (map #(.byteValue %)
         [(bit-and i 0x000000ff)
          (bit-shift-right (bit-and i 0x0000ff00) 8)
          (bit-shift-right (bit-and i 0x00ff0000) 16)
          (bit-shift-right (bit-and i 0xff000000) 24)]))))

(def leb lil-endian-bytes)

(let [wr (io/output-stream (str name ".wav") :append true)]
  (.write wr
       (byte-array (flatten (concat (map 
         (fn [sample] (leb (* 0xffff (math/sin (+ (* 2 3.14 880) sample)))))
         (range (* duration s-rate)) )))))
```

but it doesn't do what I want it to do: concat all of the byte-arrays into one vector and then into a single byte array. And it makes sense to me why it can't: it can't concat/flatten a byte[] because it's not a vector; it's a byte[]. And it can't cast a byte[] into a byte. But what do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for something like:

```
(byte-array (mapcat seq my-sequence-of-byte-arrays))
```

Comment: well, this doesn't actually do anything different than what I'm already doing unless there's something magical that's supposed to happen in the `seq` function. If so, what is that magic?

Comment: In your code, it looks like you are calling `(concat sequence-of-byte-arrays)` instead of `(concat byte-array-1 byte-array-2 ...)`.  You can fix this with `(apply concat (map ...))` or using `mapcat`.

Answer (score 4):

Converting the byte arrays to be concatenated to sequences and back to byte array may be a little inefficient if you are dealing with large arrays. Here's how to concatenate byte arrays making java.nio.ByteBuffer do the heavy lifting:

```
(defn concat-byte-arrays [& byte-arrays]
  (when (not-empty byte-arrays)
    (let [total-size (reduce + (map count byte-arrays))
          result     (byte-array total-size)
          bb         (java.nio.ByteBuffer/wrap result)]
      (doseq [ba byte-arrays]
        (.put bb ba))
      result)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be as simple as:

Your byte arrays that needs to be combined in a single byte-array:

```
(def byte-arrays [(byte-array 10 (byte 1))
                  (byte-array 10 (byte 2))
                  (byte-array 10 (byte 3))])
```

Combine:

```
(byte-array (for [ar byte-arrays
                  i ar] i))
```

Comment: This feels less idiomatic to me than either of `(byte-array (apply concat byte-arrays))` or `(byte-array (mapcat seq byte-arrays))`.  Why introduce all of the variable names?  As you said, you need to combine the byte arrays, so just `concat` them?

Comment: @ToBeReplaced I think the issue is you have to access the `byte`s from the `byte[]` in a different way than concat because it's not a collection, it's a `byte[]`. I could be definitely be wrong about that, though. Either way, this works and `(byte-array (mapcat list byte-array-collection)` didn't for me

Comment: Your distinction is incorrect. Java arrays are seqable, which is what you need for `concat` to work.  `mapcat list` did not give you the desired output because `(list [0 1])` yields `([0 1])`.  You want `(seq [0 1])`, which yields `(0 1)`.

Comment: oh, cool. I get it now. I didn't realize `seq` is an actual function (for some reason I was thinking you were using some sort of reference to a type of function there). Should've thought a little harder about that. I'm still a beginner.